# I don't see the "retag" button anymore?

Tags: support, retagging

I used to retag some questions, in particular for probability-tagged questions misusing the "distribution-theory" tag.

As I haven't got the "Edit" priviledge, I don't understand why I currently don't see the "retag" button anymore. This applies to every "open" question.

Comment: you can still retag with edit button, no peer review applies.

Comment: @CutieKrait As far as I remember this counts for only one character and I have to edit at least xx characters.

Comment: why don't you try to retag a post with edit button. just retag don't change the content.

Comment: @CutieKrait I got it now, I have to add an editing comment with at least 10 characters like "Edited tags" ...

Comment: See also [this discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/177265/kill-the-retag-option-use-just-edit) at meta.stackoverflow

Comment: @PeterPhipps Thanks for the link. I tried to find such a discussion, but wasn't successful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you hover your mouse over the tags, you'll see a hidden button which suddenly appears.

This button says "edit tags", and you can use it to retag things without going through the edit dialog.

Comment: Ok, got it now. Wouldn't it be good to change the retag privilege description?

Comment: @Asaf This was a mistake from the SE devs. That button is only expected to show for 10k+. See [MSO#182332](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182332). It has disappeared now for <10k. (I think this practice is in place to have some sort of control on retags by <10k (namely, that the question gets bumped).)

Comment: @Lord_Farin: Thanks for letting me know.